# Resource route members. Plural url with singular method name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following resource block

```
resources :projects, :except => [:destroy] do
  resources :tasks, :except => [:index]
  get "tasks/:id/change_state" => "tasks#change_state", :as => "task_change_state"
  get "tasks/:id/assign_user"  => "tasks#assign_user",  :as => "task_assign_user"
  get "tasks/:id/unassign"      => "tasks#unassign",     :as => "task_unassign"
end
```

I'm wondering how I can refactor those routes a bit without touching the path. I tried doing the following:

```
resources :projects, :except => [:destroy] do
  resources :tasks, :except => [:index] do
    member do
      get 'change_state'
      get 'assign_user'
      get 'task_unassign'
    end
  end
end
```

But that leaves the route method names with tasks as plural. I need the URL to be plural, much like in the original get method call. But I need the method name to be singular, as I would prefer to not change the implementation across the app.

Comment: Have you tried `get 'change_state', as: 'task_change_state'`, etc?

Comment: @tyler, i have. It appends task to the "tasks" part of the resource declaration. You get `projects_tasks_task_change_state_path`